# Какой есть хороший способ написать CSS для нескольких границ?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, box-shadow

Я пытаюсь создать несколько границ, которые плавно затухают вокруг изображения пользователя. Я пишу CSS, как в примере ниже, но это не то, что я хочу получить:

```
width: 90px;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow:
inset 0 0 0 4px #eee,
inset 0 0 0 8px #ddd,
inset 0 0 0 12px #ccc,
inset 0 0 0 16px #bbb,
inset 0 0 0 20px #aaa,
inset 0 0 0 20px #999,
inset 0 0 0 20px #888;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55823149/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Анимация появления при наведение границ | `box-shadow`

```css
img {
  margin: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 0 #817dd1,
    0 0 0 0 #5c58aa,
    0 0 0 0 #3d3a84,
    0 0 0 0 #211f56;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

img:hover {
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 10px #817dd1,
    0 0 0 20px #5c58aa,
    0 0 0 30px #3d3a84,
    0 0 0 40px #211f56;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">
```

---

Анимация появления из центра | `box-shadow`

```css
.img {
  margin: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.img::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #817dd1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 0 #817dd1,
    0 0 0 13.3px #5c58aa,
    0 0 0 26.6px #3d3a84,
    0 0 0 40px #211f56;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.img:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 10px #817dd1,
    0 0 0 20px #5c58aa,
    0 0 0 30px #3d3a84,
    0 0 0 40px #211f56;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">
</div>
```

Comment: А в последнем примере можешь сделать бордюры изначально круглыми?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, хмммм - [изображение](https://i.imgur.com/lslumpP.png). Ща переделаю

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `box-shadow` совместно border-radius

```css
img {
  margin: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 10px #817dd1,
    0 0 0 20px #5c58aa,
    0 0 0 30px #3d3a84,
    0 0 0 40px #211f56;
}
div {
  background: #100f35;
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
</div>
```

Если вы хотите без div:

```css
img {
  margin:40px;
  width: 90px;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow:
    0 0 0 10px #817dd1,
    0 0 0 20px #5c58aa,
    0 0 0 30px #3d3a84,
    0 0 0 40px #211f56;

}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете рассмотреть радиальный градиент и `multiple backgrounds`.

Я использовал CSS-переменные, чтобы иметь возможность легко контролировать форму (изображение, радиус, длину границы и т.д ):

```css
.avatar {
  --r: 50px; /* Внутренний радиус */
  --d: 10px; /* Ширина границ */
  width: calc(2*(var(--r) + 4*var(--d) + 1px));
  height: calc(2*(var(--r) + 4*var(--d) + 1px));
  background:
    radial-gradient(
      transparent var(--r),
      #eee calc(var(--r) + 0*var(--d) + 1px), #eee calc(var(--r) + 1*var(--d)),
      #ddd calc(var(--r) + 1*var(--d) + 1px), #ddd calc(var(--r) + 2*var(--d)),
      #ccc calc(var(--r) + 2*var(--d) + 1px), #ccc calc(var(--r) + 3*var(--d)),
      #bbb calc(var(--r) + 3*var(--d) + 1px), #bbb calc(var(--r) + 4*var(--d)),
      transparent calc(var(--r) + 4*var(--d) + 1px)),
    var(--im) center/cover content-box; /* content-box для изображения, чтобы избежать  проблем по краям */

  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px; /* Этот отступ используется с content-box для решения вопроса о крае*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block; 
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar" style="--im:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800)"></div>

<div class="avatar" style="--im:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/800);--r:20px;"></div>

<div class="avatar" style="--im:url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/800/800);--r:60px;--d:18px;"></div>
```

Вы также можете настроить размер изображения, чтобы покрыть только прозрачную часть:

```css
.avatar {
  --r: 50px; /* Внутренний радиус */
  --d: 10px; /* Ширина бордюра */
  width: calc(2*(var(--r) + 4*var(--d) + 1px));
  height: calc(2*(var(--r) + 4*var(--d) + 1px));
  background:
    radial-gradient(
      transparent var(--r),
      #eee calc(var(--r) + 0*var(--d) + 1px), #eee calc(var(--r) + 1*var(--d)),
      #ddd calc(var(--r) + 1*var(--d) + 1px), #ddd calc(var(--r) + 2*var(--d)),
      #ccc calc(var(--r) + 2*var(--d) + 1px), #ccc calc(var(--r) + 3*var(--d)),
      #bbb calc(var(--r) + 3*var(--d) + 1px), #bbb calc(var(--r) + 4*var(--d)),
      transparent calc(var(--r) + 4*var(--d) + 1px)),
    var(--im) center/calc(2*var(--r) + 2px) calc(2*var(--r) + 2px) no-repeat;

  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar" style="--im:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800)"></div>

<div class="avatar" style="--im:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/800);--r:20px;"></div>

<div class="avatar" style="--im:url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/800/800);--r:60px;--d:18px;"></div>
```

Я использую `+1px / + 2px`, чтобы избежать плохого эффекта из-за алиасинга.

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826619/7394871): @Temani Afif

Answer (score 2):

### SVG решение

Квадратную иконку аватара помещаем в круг:

```
<pattern id="ptn1" width="1" height="1">
           <image xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" x="-25" y="-10"  width="300px" height="300px" />
         </pattern>
```

Роль многоцветного бордюра выполняют окружности, окрашенные в разные цвета, как в примере решения CSS

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="450" height="450" viewBox="0 0 450 450" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
    <defs>
      <pattern id="ptn1" width="1" height="1">
     <image xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" x="-25" y="-10"  width="300px" height="300px" />
   </pattern>
    </defs>
 
 <!-- Многоцветный бордюр -->
<circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="225" fill="#211F56"/>
  <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="200" fill="#3D3A84"/>
    <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="175" fill="#5C58AA"/>
   <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150" fill="#817DD1"/> 
  <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="url(#ptn1)"/>
</svg>
```

### Примеры анимации бордюра

- Появление бордюра вокруг иконки

Запуск анимации - клик по иконке

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 450 450"   >  
    <defs>
      <pattern id="ptn1" width="1" height="1">
     <image xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" x="-25" y="-10"  width="300px" height="300px" />
   </pattern>
    </defs>

 
<circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="#211F56">
  <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="125;225" fill="freeze" />
</circle> 
 <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="#3D3A84"> 
       <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="125;200" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>
    <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="#5C58AA"> 
     <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="125;175" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>
  <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="#817DD1"> 
        <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="125;150" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>   
   
  <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="url(#ptn1)"/>
  
</svg>
```

- Бордюры открывают и окружают иконку

```html
<svg  id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 450 450"  >  
    <defs>
      <pattern id="ptn1" width="1" height="1">
     <image xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" x="-25" y="-10"  width="300px" height="300px" />
   </pattern>
    </defs>

 <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="125" fill="url(#ptn1)"/>
<g fill="none" stroke-width="25" >
 
 <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="87.5" stroke="#211F56" stroke-width="75">
   <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="87.5;200" fill="freeze" /> 
     <animate attributeName="stroke-width" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="75;25" fill="freeze" /> 
   
</circle> 
 <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="62.5" stroke="#3D3A84" stroke-width="25"> 
        <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="62.5;175" fill="freeze" />
 </circle> 
    <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="37.5" stroke="#5C58AA" stroke-width="25"> 
      <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="37.5;150" fill="freeze" /> 
 </circle> 
  <circle  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="12.5" stroke="#817DD1" stroke-width="25"> 
        <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.4s" values="12.5;125" fill="freeze" /> 
   </circle>   
 
</g>  
</svg>
```

Источник ответа: @Alexandr_TT

Comment: А почему вышего ответа нет по ассоциации на enSO? Вы только планируете там опубликовать?